# How to echo text before shell_exec in PHP

Tags: php, echo

Kindly please help me with this PHP problem. PHP file will call python file according to the user request. This python is carrying a task. I want to echo text before execute the python file. Because I want PHP to give alert on what it is going to do.

for your information, i tried a dummy file of python. the code for python is just to sleep(10);

for PHP code, I have tried to use ob_flush;, ob_start(); and all. the code is as following. as for reminder. the algorithm.py is only contain 10second sleep.:

```
ob_start();
echo "welcome";
ob_flush();
usleep(1);
$output=shell_exec("./$algorithm.py");
```

even with this code, it only echo text after finishes shell_exec. I have tried to use exec. still the text display is delayed.

Comment: First you need to use `ob_flush();` only if you actually use a buffer, but you certainly should use `flush()`.

Comment: Second there is no guarantee the browser will display partially received responses, that is not what the http protocol is meant for. You may be lucky, but to be certain you need to use a more complex approach using client side logic (javascript and ajax or web sockets) to continuously pull status information from the server and visualizing it in the already loaded page.

Answer (score 0):

[Output Buffering](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.outcontrol.php) can be used.

```
ob_implicit_flush(true)
ob_start();

echo('Task is being done');

ob_flush();

$output=shell_exec("./$algorithm.py");
echo('Wait...');

ob_flush();

echo('done.');
ob_end_flush();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "welcome"."<pre>".$output."</pre>";
```